# Array List duplicate items in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, mobile

I know this is common to ask but I've already trying `clear()` the items since before initiate the function, but it seems it always duplicate the items, This date is comes from my `MySql` database but I've check my `SQL` but it does not duplicate names and I think the problems is in code in `java` which rendered `ArratList` but I've tried `countryList.clear();` but nothings happens,need help. I have two Spinner/dropdown the second spinner depends on the first spinner list

[image]

```
   //First Dropdown Country
   public void CountryListDropdown(){
        countryList.clear();
        String url = "http://192.168.254.103/csu_clinic/populate_country.php";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("countries");
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String countryName = jsonObject.optString("country_name");
                        countryList.add(countryName);
                        countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SignUp.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryList);
//                        countryAdapter.clear();
                        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinnerCountry.setAdapter(countryAdapter);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    //Second Dropdown that depends on dropdown 1  populate list depends from dropdown one
     @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerCountry){
            cityList.clear();
            String selectedCountry = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/populate_city.php?country_name="+selectedCountry;
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("cities");
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String cityName = jsonObject.optString("city_name");
                            cityList.add(cityName);
                            cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SignUp.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityList);
                            cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spinnerCity.setAdapter(cityAdapter);



                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

Comment: You are clearing countryList before the request and populate the entries after the response. If the user manages to start the process a second time while the first is still running then you end up with duplicate entries. Therefore in `onResponse` collect the entries in a local variable and once it is finished replace the entries from countryList by the entries from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this.

```
public void CountryListDropdown() {
  String url = "http://192.168.254.103/csu_clinic/populate_country.php";
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
      try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("countries");
        countryList.clear();
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          String countryName = jsonObject.optString("country_name");
          countryList.add(countryName);
        }
        countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SignUp.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryList);
        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerCountry.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
        spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
  });
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```